# Choosing a suitable Flutter gallery package

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, image-gallery, flutter-packages

Of the packages available in flutter,is there a package that can be used to achieve the below widget of images?
[image]

Comment: Why not use `Column` and `Row`?

Comment: r u frm SriLanka ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `StaggeredGridView`

```
StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
  crossAxisCount: 4,
  mainAxisSpacing: 24,
  crossAxisSpacing: 12,
  itemCount: images.length,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
       ImageTile(image: images[index]),
  staggeredTileBuilder: (int index) => StaggeredTile.fit(2),
),
```

For [reference](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/gridview-and-staggered-gridview-in-flutter-ef5d999fcab0)

[image]